# rvest web scraping error message: "no applicable method for 'xml_find_first' applied to an object of class "character""

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to webscrape some data tables that are nested through a couple links from the initial URL. I'm still fairly new to R and used ChatGPT for some help in trying to do this, but I'm getting the error "no applicable method for 'xml_find_first' applied to an object of class "character".

Below is my code, what's going on here?

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
install.packages("XML")
library(XML)

initial_url = "https://www.ncwater.org/?page=537&tl=1&inactive=n"
initial_page = read_html(initial_url)

table_data = initial_page |> 
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
table_data = table_data[[1]]

for (i in 1:nrow(table_data)) {
  name_with_link = table_data$Name[i]
  
  anchor_tag = name_with_link |> 
    html_node("a")
  
  if (!is.na(anchor_tag)) {
    link = anchor_tag |> 
      html_attr("href")
   
    linked_page_content = GET(link) |> 
      content("text")
    linked_page = htmlParse(linked_page_content, asText = TRUE)
    
    desired_link = linked_page |> 
      html_node(xpath = "//a[contains(text(), 'Download WQ Data')]")
   
    if (!is.na(desired_link)) {
      desired_link_url = desired_link |> 
        html_attr("href")
      
      desired_link_page = read_html(desired_link_url)
      
      text_link = desired_link_page |> 
        html_element("a") |> 
        html_attr("href")
      text_file = GET(text_link)
      
      writeBin(content(text_file, "raw"), paste0(name_with_link, ".txt"))
    }
    
  }
}
```

ChatGPT hasn't been much help, I've tried every solution they've thrown at me and it isn't working. Is it possible there's something with the website itself that doesn't allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The line `html_table(fill = TRUE)` is returning a data frame from the  web page, thus stripping out all of the HTML code and links.
What you want use `html_element(initial_page, "table")` to return the first table on the web page as html and then retrieve each row from the table.  See below.
Without any comments it is not clear what information you are trying to retrieve from each link, so I will leave to the reader to work out. (maybe another question will be in order)

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)

initial_url = "https://www.ncwater.org/?page=537&tl=1&inactive=n"
initial_page = read_html(initial_url)

#get first table from page
table_data <- initial_page |> html_element("table")

#get the rows from the table
table_rows <- table_data |> html_elements("tr")

#skip the first row since that row is the headers
for (i in 2:length(table_rows)) {
   anchor_tag = table_rows[i] |> html_node("a")
   
   if (!is.na(anchor_tag)) {
      link = anchor_tag |>  html_attr("href")
      
      #need to add the domain name to the link
      link <- paste0( "https://www.ncwater.org/?", link)
      
      #get the new page (Using rvest::read_html(link)) could also work here
      linked_page_content = GET(link) |>  content("text")
      
      #Untested code
         #add code here to retrieve the desired information from page
      #end of untested code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the landing page, the items with the relevant links are those table cells containing a child anchor, in the 3rd column, which have a `title` attribute containing the string "water quality". I've added a parent element id into the CSS selector list to narrow down the search space:

`"#welllist [title*='water quality']"`

You then need to visit each of these links, which can be done in parallel. Find the anchor tag from each which has the `target` attribute (for the data) with text = "download".

`[target=download]`

You then visit each of those links, again in parallel, and target the anchor tag with the download attribute to get your final link:

`[download]`

---

Putting that together into full code to get the actual water quality data download links:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(furrr)

get_links <- function(links, css_selector_list) {
  future_map(links, ~ read_html(.x) |>
    html_element(css_selector_list) |>
    html_attr("href") |>
    url_absolute(landing))
}


landing <- "https://www.ncwater.org/?page=537&tl=1&inactive=n"
html <- read_html(landing)

initial_links <-
  html |>
  html_elements("#welllist [title*='water quality']") |>
  html_attr("href") |>
  url_absolute(landing)

# allow to run in parallel
no_cores <- future::availableCores() - 1
future::plan(future::multisession, workers = no_cores)

data_links <- get_links(initial_links, "[target=download]")

download_links <- get_links(data_links, "[download]")

# your code to handle disk write.
```